# React.js: how to create search filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make work **search input**. I'm filtering through fetched data in **useEffect** in **Hooks/useCountries** component, listening to **input** in **App.js** and passing props for **handleChange**  in **Searchbar** component. Something is missing, I can't figure out what. 
 Here is  **Hooks/useCountries** component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useCountries(search) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const searchResult =
      data &&
      data
        .filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))
        .map((element) => <div>{element.name}</div>);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return [data, error];
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
import useCountries from "./Hooks/useCountries";
import MainTable from "./components/MainTable";

import "./App.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [data, error] = useCountries(search);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchBar handleChange={handleChange} search={search} />
      <MainTable countries={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

SearchBar component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./SearchBar.scss";

export default function Searchbar({ handleChange, search }) {
  return (
    <div className="SearchBar">
      <input
        className="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="search country ..."
        value={search}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` method you have which performs the filtering needs to be fired each time the search term changes - currently you are only using it once when the hook is created for the first time:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const searchResult =
      data &&
      data
        .filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))
        .map((element) => <div>{element.name}</div>);
  }, [search]);
```

Note how the `search` variable is now part of the `useEffect` dependency array.

Comment: hey @Phobos thanks for asnwer. Actually I'd tried,  but it doesn't work.